# Tracking everything locally but making only .c and .h changes available on github

Tags: windows, git, github, tortoisegit, gitk

I'm going to start tracking a project I'm working on using TortoiseGit. I have a lot of .c and .h files, and then I also have .exe, .obj, .pdb, .ilk, suo, etc. I would like to create a snapshot of everything, all those files. So that I can roll back to a prior revision if necessary. However after a few weeks I want to upload all those revisions to github but I would like people to see only the .c and .h file changes and have only those files visible in the clean public version of the project. I'm new to git and not sure how best to go about this. The closest question I found (but don't understand really) is here:

[Push a branch of a git repo to a new remote (github), hiding its history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020553/push-a-branch-of-a-git-repo-to-a-new-remote-github-hiding-its-history)

Is that what I want to do? Can someone break it down for me with a step by step that I can do using gitk (Git GUI with msysgit) or tortoisegit? My experience level is I've read the GitBook but not the advanced section yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the link to the question and the answers given for it are the way to go for this.

Another way ( which many may frown upon ) is that you can put your git repo in a git repo. This way, commit the local binaries etc. in the outter repo, but ignore them in the inner one. Also ignore `.git` from the inner repo in the outter repo. This will enable you to go back to some older version of the binaries and corresponding version of the source.

Comment: Thanks but I don't really understand how to do what is detailed in that question. Is there any way to bump my question so that someone else can see it and maybe give me a step by step on how I can do it in TortoiseGit?